# Kernel version fairness in the context of CFS scheduler

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

In the Linux kernel:

> a) What does fairness mean in the context of the CFS scheduler?
>
> b) Are there other definitions of fairness?
>
> c) How does the CFS scheduler select tasks to run? What is the main
>   data structure used?
>
> d) How does the BFS design differ from the CFS design?

Any suggestion is welcomed!

Thank you

Comment: This is not a homework service. Check text books, Wikipedia, and the search engine of your choice. Post only specific programming questions here, and include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is not a homework problem. I was reading about fairness and did not understand the parts in the questions.